# Best way to migrate a list or document library from one MOSS server to another?

Tags: migration

I have a requirement to move a few lists and document libraries from one MOSS server to another.

Is there an easy to use tool that can accomplish this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using stsadm is probably the best option.
You could off-course use the Windows Explorer view on both lists and copy the documents from one list to the other using a plain copy-paste action.

Answer (score 0):

I've had good success using the stsadm extensions:  http://stsadm.blogspot.com/2009/02/downloads.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to give this one a try http://gspmigrator.codeplex.com/ have tried but seems to do what you looking for